# Delete duplicates and keep the topmost value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates

I have consolidated two columns of data into one column in my spreadsheet, and color-coded them. There are about 300 duplicates in the list.

How would I delete duplicates and keep the topmost value?

Using the Delete Duplicates or Filter > Advanced Filter (with unique records only) removes duplicates from both lists (in the same column). I want the topmost list (which I have colored differently to the bottom one) to stay the same and the bottom list which may have duplicates from the top list to be shortened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can highlight the second area and use `Remove Duplicates` to just remove duplicates from this selected area.

Assuming the first range is A2:A7 and the second range follows this from A8, enter the following formula into B2 and copy all the way down:

```
IF(AND(ROW(A2)>ROW($A$7),COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,A2)>0),"remove","keep")
```

This will ignore the first range ("keep") and indicate "remove" for rows in the second range that occur in the first range. You can then `AutoFilter` the area and delete the data with "remove".

You could use instead this simpler version of the formula, which just inserts TRUE or FALSE:

```
=AND(ROW(A2)>ROW($A$7),COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,A2)>0)
```

This will remove all duplicates in the second area though. That is, it won't keep the first of the duplicated values. **Added** actually, if you want to keep the first of these, you could use `Remove Duplicates` again, based on the second area and both columns' values.

Comment: OK thanks, I understand up to the AutoFilter bit. Which area do I autofilter?

Comment: "Which area do I autofilter?" I don't understand: the area that contains the word "remove" (or TRUE, if you use the 2nd formula).